# Do auto properties affect runtime performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

When you declare a member variable like this: `public bool name { get; set; }` There is always a performance hit when accessing it, right?

I see that pattern a lot and imagine in some higher-performance applications it can add up with frequently access properties. Am I correct, or does .NET do something behind the scenes?

Comment: Nope.  There is no difference.  The compiler generates a backing variable when you use the shorthand.

Comment: This is just a syntactic sugar

Comment: I believe using this style actually creates a Property rather than a member variable.  It only matters in a limited number of situations.

Comment: @RacerNerd The compiler *can't* change a Property to a Field - that's a breaking binary compatibility change.

Comment: An auto-implemented property should only have a negligible performance hit... now if your `get` does some horrible O(n^2) algorithm on a large data-structure then you *will* have problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Auto-properties desugar into a backing field plus trivial accessor bodies. The JIT inlines them reliably if optimizations are turned on. Performance is identical to a field.

Just use auto-properties without regret. Visual Studio has a `prop` template. Type `prop<tab><tab>` to get one. `propg` is for a private setter, which is useful to quickly stamp out immutable types.

Comment: I confirmed this in a recent post. The generated (64-bit JITer code on my machine anyway) code does in fact inline the call and ends up identical to accessing the backing field directly. +1.

Comment: The `prop` template is not exclusive to Resharper. It is by default available in VS (2010). Use `propg` if you want a `private set` immediately.